# How to use the C++11 random generators efficiently?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, random

I am executing computational experiments, which need to be **reproducible**. Therefore each experiment uses its own random number generator and remembers its seed:

```
class Experiment
{
public:
    void operator()();
private:
    unsigned seed_;
    std::mt19937 engine_;
};
```

The problem is that the engine needs to be passed down to the most elementary functions.

Let's say that somewhere 10 levels down the call stack there is a simple function that needs an engine to generate a random number between 0 and 1. Then that engine needs to be passed to each of those 10 calls, making the code a mess.

I considered and refused these two approaches:

```
1. global engine:
```

I would have a global engine and all the elementary functions would call this engine. This could however cause problems if I wanted to run several experiments in different **threads**. I have zero experience in multithreading, but I got a lot of advice against anything global, especially in a multithreaded application and I do not want to make a step in the wrong direction.

```
2. local engine in each small function.
```

Each function would create an engine on the stack, use it and destroy it on return. This could however cause **performance** problems, since the random number generator is a big complicated object. On my implementation it has 5000 bytes.

What approach should I use?

Comment: Can all your "simple functions" be members of your `Experiment` class?

Comment: @KerrekSB I would prefer not to, since some of them are from the standard library, like `std::shuffle`

Comment: *"Then that engine needs to be passed to each of those 10 calls, making the code a mess."* You'll only ever need to pass *the* engine, i.e. the `std::mt19937`. You can create the *distributions* locally, which can be cheap e.g. for simple distributions such as `uniform_int_distribution`. What exactly is messy about passing an additional argument?

Comment: Maybe a thread-local random generator. Main disadvantage: It's hidden mutable state.

Comment: @dyp Yes, that is exactly what I am doing now. The problem is that I am passing the generator to functions that, on first sight, have nothing to do with random numbers, thus making the source code less readable. That is all.

Comment: @usr that sounds good! However I do not have many experiences with threads. Is there something I can do now, that would prevent me from changing a lot of code in the future?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik you can use a global now and later mechanically switch to using a thread-local. However, it can still be hard to get this to work with parallelism. You probably want to start each parallel worker with a given seed. Now you have to shove that seed into the thread-local of that worker. All doable, but there's a lot of magic going on implicitly. I'd rather go with Kerrek's idea of explicitly passing the all mutable state.

Comment: @usr Thank you! Do you mean using the `thread_local` specifier?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik I have no idea. I'm not proficient with C++.

Comment: @Martin I'd really absent from using thread local without *really* good reasons. It's even worse than global state from a readability and maintenance point of view (I work on code that uses it quite a bit - for entirely justified reasons - and it's not fun). I'm still not entirely satisfied with your explanation why you can't share the engine in a class. Sure you may have to pass that argument once to the standard lib functions, but that's at most a single level of indirection.

Comment: @dyp some distribution implementations will cache unused bits of entropy so creating one each time may be wasteful.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Interesting! I looked up once the implementation of `uniform_int_distribution` in libstdc++, which IIRC didn't do anything fancy. I guess it'll be hard to pass around many of the distribution objects if you're using different distributions in different functions.

Comment: _I would prefer not to, since some of them are from the standard library, like `std::shuffle`_ But you're not just calling `std::shuffle`, because you need to provide the RNG, so having a member function that calls `std::shuffle` with the `engine_` member seems sensible. Arguably better than a global anyway.

Comment: If you keep creating a new local engine then you keep getting the same initial state. Goodbye randomness.

Comment: Why not use a global generator, and lock it each time you request a number using mutexes. If this is too slow, request the numbers in blocks. Otherwise you can assign generators to each thread, each deterministically seeded from one global seed.

Comment: @RossHemsley I need a generator in each thread, otherwise the results would not be reproducible. I think I will just pass the generator to each function that needs it as suggested by

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get reproducible random numbers is to use the seed when you initialize your  random umber generators.
For the speed you should not be too concerned as these objects are not that big.

Here is an example

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// uniform_real_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


void generateNumbers(std::vector<double>& vRes, unsigned int nbNumbers, int seed, double & sum)
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);//forcing this parameter will force the results to      be the samme so you only need to keep track  of one number
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);//uniform distribution between 0 and 1.0

   sum=0.0;
   vRes.resize(nbNumbers);
   for (unsigned int i=0;i<nbNumbers;++i)
   {
       vRes[i]=distribution(generator);
       sum+=vRes[i];
   }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const unsigned int nbNumbers=1000000;
    const int seed=100;
    const int nbThreads=300;
    std::vector<std::vector<double > > vTest(nbThreads);
    std::vector<double> vSum(nbThreads);//vector of checksums: all numbers should be the same as we sum the same random numbers

    for (int currThread=0;currThread<nbThreads;++currThread)
    {
        std::thread th(&generateNumbers, vTest[currThread],nbNumbers,seed,std::ref(vSum[currThread]));
        th.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code runs in less than 10seconds in Release Visual Studio 2012. It can be greatly improved by using less threads (thread creation is time consuming) but that gives the idea.

Hope that it helps,

Comment: Note that distributions (as opposed to random number engines) have no standard implementation in C++, so the random numbers those distributions deliver are not necessarily reproducible.  Note also that in your code, all the threads are passed the same seed.

Comment: regarding the seed, it is more about have a reproductible behaviour than having a pure random function. I am assuming in my example all the threads are independant, so using the same seed would not be a problem. Nothing prevents you from using a different one